# Parsing emoticons with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a `textarea` that functions as a comment box, and a `div` that shows the rendered preview of the comment. I want to be able to parse emoticons and render them as images in the preview area.

With the code below, some emoticons work but others don't. The ones that don't work are: `angel, arrow, at, :-], :-?, B-), B), ;), exclamation, <3, huh, my, roll, :(, shy, |-), :-P`

I'm not sure why these others aren't working.

JavaScript:

```
var smileys = {
    ':)': '<img src="smilies/smile.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    ':-)': '<img src="smilies/smile.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    ':D': '<img src="smilies/smile.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    ':-(': '<img src="smilies/angry.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    'angel': '<img src="smilies/angel.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    'arrow': '<img src="smilies/arrow.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    'at': '<img src="smilies/at.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    ':-D': '<img src="smilies/biggrin.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    'lol': '<img src="smilies/biggrin.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    ':-]': '<img src="smilies/blush.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    ':-?': '<img src="smilies/confused.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    'B-)': '<img src="smilies/cool.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    'B)': '<img src="smilies/cool.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    ';)': '<img src="smilies/dodgy.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    'exclamation': '<img src="smilies/exclamation.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    '<3': '<img src="smilies/heart.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    'huh': '<img src="smilies/huh.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    'my': '<img src="smilies/my.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    'roll': '<img src="smilies/rolleyes.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    ':(': '<img src="smilies/sad.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    ':-(': '<img src="smilies/sad.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    'shy': '<img src="smilies/shy.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    '|-)': '<img src="smilies/sleepy.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    ':-P': '<img src="smilies/tongue.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    ':-|': '<img src="smilies/undecided.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    ';-)': '<img src="smilies/wink.gif" border="0" alt="" />'
};


$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".chat > textarea").bind("keyup", function(e) {
    $(".chat > div").html(smilyMe($(".chat > textarea").val()));
  });
});

function smilyMe(msg) {
  //smiley replace
  msg=msg.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
  return msg.replace(/(\:\)|\:-\)|\:D|\:-D|\blol\b|\:-\||\:-\(|\;-\))/g, function(all) {
    return smileys[all] || all;
    return str;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add more capturing groups to your regex expression:

```
msg.replace(/(\:\)|\:-\)|\:D|\:-D|\blol\b|\:-\||\:-\(|\;-\)|angel|arrow)/g
-----------------------------------------------------------^ here
```

Each item separated by `|` pipes `|` is a potential match for `msg.replace()`. When you add more items to the `smileys` object, you'll also have to add more groups to the regex expression.

You could do something like this to avoid that:

```
function smilyMe(msg) {
    msg = msg.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');

    for (var key in smileys) {
        msg = msg.replace(key, smileys[key]);
    }

    return msg;
}
```

**Edit**: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzyq7s1e/1/) for you with the above implementation.

Answer (score 1):

use for to loop through your object with the smilies so you only have to define them once.
here is a working example with your code: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgqhx9a6/2/)

```
function smilyMe(msg) {
  for (var key in smileys) {

      var match = new RegExp(key.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&"), "g");
      msg = msg.replace(match, smileys[key]);

   }
  return msg
}
```